# creating indicator variables using multiple columns using "contains" in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to know how to create an indicator variable using over 100 columns.

If we have multiple columns like DX1-DX100, how can I create this indicator?
Can we use "contains" using dplyr?

```
data<-data.frame(id=seq(1,10,1),DX1=c(4,0,4,0,0,5,6,0,0,0),DX2=c(1,0,0,7,0,0,0,7,0,0),DX3=c(1,0,1,0,1,7,1,0,0,0)) 
data$indicator<-ifelse(data$DX1>=3|data$DX2>=3|data$DX3>=3,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
data$indicator <- if_else(rowSums(select(data, starts_with("DX"))) > 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
I would like to use this for both categorical and numeric variables.
data<-data.frame(id=seq(1,10,1), DX1=c(4,0,4,0,0,5,6,0,0,0),DX2=c(1,0,0,7,0,0,0,7,0,0),DX3=c(1,0,1,0,1,7,1,0,0,0))

data$indicator<-ifelse(data$DX1==5|data$DX2==5|data$DX3==5,1,0)

Comment: Could you please update your question to include categorical variables in the example data?

Answer (score 0):

One option is

```
data$indicator <- as.integer(Reduce(`|`, data[-1]))
```

#### Update

Based on the comments

```
as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(data[-1], `>=`, 5)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I would like to use this for both categorical and numeric variables. data<-data.frame(id=seq(1,10,1), DX1=c(4,0,4,0,0,5,6,0,0,0),DX2=c(1,0,0,7,0,0,0,7,0,0),DX3=c(1,0,1,0,1,7,1,0,0,0)) data$indicator<-ifelse(data$DX1>=5|data$DX2>=5|data$DX3>=5,1,0)